# Data binding between sibling elements in a Polymer dom-bind template

Tags: data-binding, binding, polymer, polymer-2.x

I have a `<dom-bind>` template containing two elements - one is a button, the other a list. When the list is loading (it's `loading` property is `true`), the buttons `active` property should be set to `false`, and vice versa.

I can't get the binding between them to work. Of course I could create a new element out of the whole thing, but I'd rather avoid it if possible.

This is my `<dom-bind>` template:

```
<dom-bind id="messageListScreen">
    <template>
        <paper-progress-button on-click="fetchNewMessages" active="[[!loading]]" active-text="Refresh" inactive-text="Refreshing..." raised></paper-progress-button>
        <message-grid id="grid" loading="{{loading}}"></message-grid>
    </template>
</dom-bind>
```

With the above code, nothing happens. If I do this

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("WebComponentsReady", function(event){
        let self = document.getElementById('messageListScreen');
        self.loading = self.$.grid.loading;
    });
</script>
```

`self.loading` does get the value of `grid.loading`, but when the value of `grid.loading` changes, the value of `self.loading` stays the same.

Is there any way to bind the value of `grid.loading` to the `active` property of the `<paper-progress-button>` using `<dom-bind>`?

Comment: Try initializing your loading property (i.e. `document.querySelector('messageListScreen').loading`) _outside_ of the `WebComponentsReady` listener. This is the only detail in which your example obviously deviates from that in the official docs (https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-bind).

Comment: @craPkit Still doesn't seem to work... I looked at that official docs example before, but their data binding is only "one way", in that it is only set once and then never changed. Remember, it's the two-way binding that I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use two-way binding.

Add `notify:true` to the `loading` properties in `message-grid`, and set the loading in `message-grid` via `this.set('loading', false)` (instead of `this.loading = false`).

You should also have a property called `loading` in `messageListScreen` too. You probably have, you don't need it, but it's nice for documentation.

---

Another thing is that boolean attributes are always true if they are present, hence loading will always be true in both cases, no matter what values the attribute has (true||false). Switch the boolean to a number (int) instead, where 1 is true and 0 is false.

Comment: Great, `notify: true` did the trick! Not sure how you mean that boolean attributes are always true if present? I initialize loading to `false` in the properties declaration, and then it's set by a `<iron-ajax>`...

Comment: Booleans are set in tags as <tag booleanname> so if booleanname is present, that sets the boolean value to true. If it's not present, it sets it to false.